# How to get Onion v3 private key

Tags: configuration, onion-routing

I have genarated a castom onion v3 domain by using mkp224o
i got 3 file 
1. hostname
2. hs_ed25519_public_key
3. hs_ed25519_secret_key

but i need private key . how can i get private key from this 3 file

Answer (score 1):

Actually everything is OK. You just need to copy these three files to a folder on your system. Then add these lines to your torrc:

```
HiddenServiceDir THE_DIRECTORY_WHICH_THE_FILES_ARE_INCLUDED
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

which 80 is the hidden service port (i.e. abcdefghijklmnop.onion:80) and will be tunneled to 127.0.0.1.

If you are using TOR 2 (tor 0.2.x) you should add an extra line to torrc:

```
HiddenServiceVersion 3
```

More info:
https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-onion-service.html.en